# Laravel get model available seats

Tags: laravel, eloquent

What I'm trying to to do is get available seats of a place, seats model has a quantity field and also has a category, so let's just say that a seat has a quantity of 10, i want to count the reservations on a specific date and on a specific seat for each seat in a seat category and do a where statement to find what seats are available like:

`where('reservations_count', '<', 'seat_quantity')`

Is this kind of thing possible in one Eloquent query, all of the models have a relationship with each other, i just can't figure out how to get the availability for each seat.

What i have done so far, not even close of what i'm trying to do:

```
    $seats = SeatCategory::where('place_id', $data['place']['id'])->with('seats', function($q) use ($date) {
        $q->whereDoesntHave('reservations', function($q) use ($date) {
            $q->where('date', $date);
        });
    })->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting first the Seat Categories with their seats and using each made it work like a charm.

```
$categories = SeatCategory::where('place_id', $data['place']['id'])->with('seats')->get();

    $categories->each(function($item, $key) use ($date, $categories) {
        $item->seats->each(function($item2, $key2) use ($date, $categories, $key) {
            $reservations = Reservation::where('seat_id', $item2['id'])->whereBetween('date', [$date->startOfDay()->toDateTimeString(), $date->endOfDay()->toDateTimeString()])->count();
            

            $categories[$key]->seats[$key2]->calc_quantity = intval($categories[$key]->seats[$key2]->quantity) - intval($reservations);

            if(intval($reservations) >= intval($item2['quantity'])) {
                unset($categories[$key]->seats[$key2]);
            };
        });
    });
```